# Problem with demodulation system, LTspice

Tags: ltspice, demodulation

First of all, I'm sorry if my English isn't perfect, that's not my natural language.

I'm trying to simulate an electronic system for my project and I want to demodulate a sinusoidal signal.
To do that, I use a demodulation system with AOP and Switch. You can find a screenshot of my system attached at this post.

I add an complementary module, which create a square signal to command my switch. But, when I simulate my system, the AOP does not demodulate my signal and it outputs a sinusoidal signal :/

My objective is to demodulate my sinusoidal signal and use a low pass filter to have a signal centered on 5V +/- 4 V DC at the output.

P.S :
Ue and output are the same on screenshot.

Schematic:

[image: Schematic]

Simulation result:

- In pink, UE and switch_Output
- In light green, Output system
- In light blue, switch command

[image: Simulation result]

Comment: *demodulate a sinusoidal signal.* **How** is the sinusoid modulated, amplitude modulation (AM), frequency modulated (FM) or something else?

Comment: What supply are you using for `U9`? Is the 8th pin of `ADG419` meant to be be left floating?

Comment: The sinusoid is created by an transformator (with 2 coils, one primary one secondary) so I haven't information about how it is modulated. The only thing I know it's the sinusoid is center on 5V.

For the second commentary, it's +15-0V supply. The 8th pin of ADG419 is the NC pin of my switch, PIN 1 is for D, PIN 2 is for S1 with NO switch (information from the technical doc)

But I haven't the last version of LTSpice, i'm updating it, and will see if it's work

Comment: So, I think my ADG419 is just broken (I downloaded it on Analog Device Website and generated it from the Spice model wich they give) 

I changed it for the ADG1634, and it's work perfectly !

Comment: @BenjaminM When replying to someone, be sure to use the `@<TAB>` to cycle between names, otherwise they will not get feedback. You say you have a supply for `U9`, but your picture shows an opamp without any connection for its power pins. If you do have a supply, you should include it in your picture, to avoid confusion. Now, if you say it's working, it's too late, of course, but please remember it next time.